# Can I add Sharepoint site to Outlook desktop app

Tags: sharepoint, outlook, onedrive

I can not find any option to add "Sharepoint site" so that it appears just below my mailbox list

Initially I tried to add OneDrive to Outlook, but I failed. Then I raised a call with Microsoft and they confirmed that it is not possible. My CEO has used this feature in another organization. Tried to add account from File --> Account Settings --> Add account, but can not add URL for "Sharepoint site". I do not want to use 3rd party app in our Email system. App launcher in Outlook does not have "Sharepoint folder" option. I created a custom app tile which now only appearing only on the web. My CEO wants to drag file attachment and email directly to site without leaving Outlook.

Can someone help me please?

Many thanks.